# How to solve the integral $\int x\cdot 9\cdot x^{2x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

> How to solve the integral $$\int x\cdot 9\cdot x^{2x^2} dx$$

I tried $u=2x^2$ and $du= 4x\;dx\Longrightarrow$ $$\int x\cdot9\cdot x^{2x^2}\;dx=\frac94\int x^u du$$But it was unable to pass.

Comment: The result cannot be found in terms of standard mathematical functions. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%28x%5E%7B2x%5E2%2B1%7D%29&dataset=&equal=Submit

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%289*x*x%5E%282x%5E2%29%29 I just put this into wolframalpha out of curiosity, and got this results. I think you may be fighting a losing battle here :-)

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't $9xe^{2x^2}$? With base $e$, not $x$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^{2x^2}=(x^2)^{x^2}=y^y$ . Also, $y'(x)=(x^2)'=2x$. Then our integral becomes $\displaystyle\frac92\int y^ydy$ , which, despite looking much prettier, is however still not expressible in terms of elementary functions. :-)